# Can't find variable: google , Ipod touch google chart

Tags: javascript, ipod-touch, google-visualization

I'm using the exact code as the

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart.html

works fine browser, Ipad ... but when i use my Ipod with the Debug:ON , show a javascript error :

> "Can't find variable: google"

Any Idea how to solve? Same happens if i try to access the page of google.

There is a work around?